# Open email client AND submit a form using PHP / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email

I know how to submit a form.  I know how to use a mailto: link.  What I can't figure out is how to do both when the user clicks a single link (or button).

Is there a way to both submit form data and open the email client?  Was thinking some variation of a mailto: link with an onclick JavaScript attached; but I can't figure out how to submit form data without clicking a Submit button.  (Or the flipside -- opening the user's email client with JavaScript attached to the Submit click?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a combination of JavaScript / jQuery and HTML. Create a link using `a` and add the `onclick` parameter to it, which can trigger the form submission:

Using jQuery:

```
<a href="mailto:youremail@domain.com" onclick="$('#myform').submit();">Submit</a>
```

Using JavaScript:

```
<a href="mailto:youremail@domain.com" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to first open the email client, and then send automatically the email **through** the email client, that is not possible.

Otherwise, Niraj's answer suits well, but it will:

1. Open the email client
2. Submit the email
3. Leave the email client opened